# Natural Logs and Anit-Derivatives are kicking me

Tags: integration, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

I am given a problem involving rates of flow, $F(t)=\frac{t+7}{2+t}$ is the rate at which a bucket is being filled. The same bucket is being emptied at a rate given by $E(t)=\frac{\ln(t+4)}{t+2}$. My job is to find the number of pints left in the bucket after five minutes, yes t is in minutes. I know the equation looks something like... $\int_0^5{F(t)dt}-\int_0^5{E(t)dt}$    and maybe it would look like this... $\int_0^5{F(t)-E(t)dt}$. But I don't know how to get the anti-derivative of E(t). I have worked it down further to exclude the theory that my problem involves polylogarithms. It is now $\int_0^5{\frac{t+7-\ln(t+4)}{t+2}}$

Comment: Is it really a $4$ on top and a $2$ on the bottom? Terminology: an equation is, among other things, an equality. What you're given is a function.

Comment: yes that is correct, I just fixed it.

Comment: You didn't fix anything I told you, but good work with the formatting. Anyway, there probably is a typo in the problem, most likely two $2$s or two $4$s are intended.

Comment: I'll edit it for the FULL problem.

Comment: it's fixed, i think

Comment: @EricSchwarz Are you allowed to use a calculator for this problem?

Comment: Yes, I am allowed to

Comment: @EricSchwarz On most graphing calculators there is a feature which allows one to numerically calculate definite integrals without determining the antiderivative. For this integral, you will not able to find the antiderivative (at least not easily). Other than that, your integral expression seems fine. Watch out for initial values, though it doesn't seem like they were given.

Answer (score 0):

For problems like this, I think the convention is to use numerical integration, approximations using Simpson's rule in your calculator, the part you're responsible for is setting up the integrals. I attempted to integrate E(t) and I'm fairly certain the answer would require some special function like polylogarithms.